# What are the most recent StackOverflow datasets on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, stackexchange-api

What are the most recent StackOverflow datasets on BigQuery? Two datasets I am aware of are very much out of date. Are there more recent ones?

1. `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow` referenced on https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/stack-exchange/stack-overflow?project=stackoverflowquery-407019 (and also in "Hello, world" google bigquery tutorial...) has not been updated since 24 Nov 2022 (see the screenshot).
2. Datasets mentioned by Filipe Hoffe [here](https://hoffa.medium.com/finding-the-real-top-stack-overflow-questions-aebf35b095f1) have 2019 as their most recent data (`SELECT distinct quarter FROM` fh-bigquery.stackoverflow_archive_questions.merged  query, results are below).

[image]

```
Row((datetime.date(2017, 6, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2017, 3, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2017, 12, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2018, 6, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2019, 3, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2018, 9, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2017, 9, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2018, 3, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
Row((datetime.date(2018, 12, 1),), {'quarter': 0})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the *bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.posts_questions*" details, this table was last updated on *Nov 25, 2022, 5:10:40 AM UTC+5:30*.

This is a known issue, there is a  request filed for the [same](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/283828498). You can vote for this by clicking the `+1` and `STAR` mark to receive updates on it.

As a workaround, If you want to query directly using the BQ console you can consider storing stack overflow’s open-source dataset files in the Google Cloud storage and can be queried directly on the BQ console.

For more information, you can refer to these [link1](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/public-datasets/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a),[link2](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/15/you-can-now-play-with-stack-overflow-data-on-googles-bigquery/) and [link3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97067/where-i-can-find-stack-overflow-s-open-source-dataset).